# Обработка смены ориентации ViewPager

Tags: android-fragment, android-viewpager, android-bundle, orientation

Уже весь интернет перерыл и так и не смог реализовать обработку смены ориентации.
Есть фрагмент с адаптером для viewPager.
Создаю метод:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    CURRENT_TAB = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    outState.putInt("current_tab", CURRENT_TAB);
}
```

Здесь всё правильно проставляется - позиция например 2.

Далее создаётся:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AppPreferences appPreferences = new AppPreferences(getContext());

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        CURRENT_TAB = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_tab");
        viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(CURRENT_TAB);
            }
        });
    }
```

......

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orderlist, container, false);
 savedInstanceState.getString("current_tab"));
```

Что в первом, что во втором случае savedInstanceState null. Почему? Как правильно обработать смену ориентации?